# Angular 8: Is there any way to parse the template(that has angular code eg:ngFor) and get the HTML output inside typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript, parsing, data-binding, interpolation

I have the below HTML template that I receive it as part of API response that has the angular code (eg: binding, ngFor etc..). After I get the response from API, I will need to map array of JSON objects to this template (for data binding) and get the final output with parsed contents. I am using Angular 8. I remember in Angular JS, we had $interpolate. Let me know if anybody has idea on how to achieve this in Angular 2+ ? Thanks in advance

```
Code:

getDataFromAPI(){
this.reportData = {
metaData: [
        [
          {
            'label' : 'test1',
            'value' : 'test2'
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            'label' : 'test3',
            'value' : 'test4'
          }
        ],
        
      ];
}
this.service.fetchData(params).subscribe(response => {
  Response is HTML template with angular code
});
}
```

API response:

```
<table *ngFor="let eachMetadata of reportData.metaData" class="tableContainer">
<tr class="metadata">
<td *ngFor="let eachMetadataItem of eachMetadata" class="metadataLabel">{{eachMetadataItem.label}}
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="metadata">
<td *ngFor="let eachMetadataItem of eachMetadata" class="metadataValue">
{{eachMetadataItem.value}}
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Parsing HTML in Angular is non-intuitive and discouraged. Also what you're asking for doesn't make much sense. Why not send the `reportData` as a JSON from the backend and write the template in the frontend directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MichaelD . Just to give more context.. this is mainly for displaying this HTML output contents in PDF format using pdfmake library. I need to pass this HTML output to the library. The  HTML template that you see above is generic one and we have different modules where each module has its own data but in the same format that I mentioned above for reportData. Module 1 as reportData and it will call the API to get the template and along with that it will need to pass reportData to get the final ouput.. same thing for other modules as well. Hope I clarified the points

Comment: eg: this is typescript code const reportContainer = this.reportContainer.nativeElement;
    var html = htmlToPdfmake(reportContainer.innerHTML);        and in HTML we have this code <div [innerHTML]="htmlTemplate" #reportContainer>